# Marketing Cloud - Making the image of an In-app message fill the whole screen

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way to remove the space around an In-app message's image and make it fill the remaining space?

I have removed the title, description, and buttons of the message, but the space around the image is still there. I'm already using the Fill image layout in Journey builder.

In the picture below, the **red area** is the image I used in the message, and the **gray area** is the background of my application. I want to be able to remove the gray area and make the image fill the remaining space. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the "Full" and "FullImageFill" templates. Your only option is to better size your image -- maybe go larger and ensure the areas of interest are within a safe margin as to not be cropped.

I tried `FullImageFill` with https://dummyimage.com/2048x4096/777777/ffffff.png&text=This+is+a+Large+Image and got this result:

[image]

Comment: Gotcha, thing is that we deal with a lot of different devices, so finding an image that fits every one is practically impossible. Also, our images have a lot of color, making the contrast between the background and foreground very noticeable if the image doesn't perfectly fit, which is a bit of a bummer.

Comment: In your other question I also discuss how to override the XML used by the SDK. You could probably figure out a fit-stretch-crop-whatever solution for the ImageView that suits your needs better, but I'm `NOT` (capital N not) recommending you do this and will not guarantee the results when you open a support ticket :P

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at the other post.